# Having problem with npm login, it returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-publish

I just faced the problem with npm adduser & npm login.

Here is the command `npm adduser --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com --scope=@ksheyon123` & `npm adduser --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com --scope=@ksheyon123`

Both of command returns 403 Forbidden error.
[image]

Of course it is my accounts.

[image]

In my package.json

```
{
"name": "@ksheyon123/react-componentkit",
  "version": "2.0.0", // I have never used over 2.0.0 version. (It is highest version)
  "description": "Component Kit library for the React",
  "publishConfig": {
    "@ksheyon123:registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/"
  },
 ...my package.json
}
```

This is my .nvmrc in the root

```
@ksheyon123:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=npm_xxxxx
```

My github & npm profile

[image]
[image]

Does anybody know the reason of this problem?

> More Info

Access npm adduser & npm login without --registry flags is success. And, I can publish the package.

[image]

But, there is no packages in my account.

[image]
[image]

Comment: **Solved problem** It was publishing target related issue